# Como hacer una consulta de datos en HTML utilizando javascritp o .json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, bootstrap, base-de-datos

Saludos estoy trabajando en un proyecto Html con bootstrap en el mismo tengo que hacer unas consultas de datos por medio de un ID. pero al ser pocos datos no quiero hacer una base de datos e investigado un poco pero solo encuentro filtrar tablas, pero el asunto es que no quiero que se muestren los datos sino hasta realizar la busqueda por eso filtrar tablas no me conviene.

Se me oucrre manejar los datos en archivos .json o javascritp perno no se como empezar. Me pueden echar una mano o algun consejo como iniciar.

en el siguiente ejemplo se muestran los datos pero yo no quiero que esten visualmente hasta que se aplique el filtro y no quiero que filtre hasta que se presione el boton.

```js
angular.module('busquedaAvanzada', [])
        .controller('busquedaController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.lista = [
                {nombre: 'Pepe', apellido: 'Trueno'},
                {nombre: 'Kava', apellido: 'Zorro'},
                {nombre: 'Rosa', apellido: 'Melo'},
                {nombre: 'Elmo', apellido: 'Jones'},
                {nombre: 'Gato', apellido: 'Negro'}
            ];
        }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Busqueda Angular</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="buscar.js"> </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="busquedaAvanzada">
    <input type="text" ng-model="busqueda">
    <button>Enviar</button>

    <table ng-controller="busquedaController">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in lista | filter: busqueda">
                <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{item.apellido}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: quieres hacer una busqueda con datos ficticios cierto @josue Gonzales

Comment: Esos datos no van a sufrir cambios? siempre realizarás una consulta? nunca alta, modificación o eliminación?

Comment: Empieza buscando en Google alguna alternativa. Filtrar las tablas me parece una buena alternativa, te sugiero que lo intentes, simplemente no muestres nada mientras la caja de búsqueda esté vacía. Mejora tu pregunta o será cerrada. Te sugiero que agregues un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender __lo que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema__.

Comment: puedes hacer un archivo .json y recorrerlo agregarlo al .html y te funcionaria

Comment: Los datos seran añadidos y modificados solo por el administrador de la pagina osea por el backend.

Comment: @JosueGonzalez mi hermano prueba con la respuesta que ti recuerdas que ese plugin tienes que importarlo en tu html , ojo tienes que descargar el plugin y instanciar en el html

Answer (score 1):

Si no es un problema usar jQuery, la solución con un archivo json y javascript is bastante fácil de implementar:

El archivo json con los datos lo ubicas en el servidor en una carpeta accesible desde la web.

En el archvio javascript definir un objeto global para la aplicación donde alojar los datos una vez recibidos:

```
var MiApp = function(){
    this.data = [];
}

var miApp = new MiApp();
```

Luego para buscar el contenido y guardarlo en un objeto en javascript lo bajas utilizando `$.ajax`. Se puede hacer sin jQuery pero con jQuery es mucho más fácil.

En el ejemplo la función buscarDatos() hace la llamada de ajax, por eso la ejecutamos al recibir el click en el boton *Bajar Datos*.

Una vez que se ejecuta la función buscarDatos() - que tiene la llamada de ajax -  los datos quedan disponibles en miApp.data.

En el ejemplo agregué un boton para mostrar el contenido de miApp.data.

Para mejorarlo podrias pasarle un parametro a la función buscarData() con el nombre a devolver y filtrar ese resultado en la función success de ajax.

Importante:
Al estar el archivo en el webserver puede ser consultado directamente poniendo la url en el browser.

Y poniendo un breakpoint en la función de ajax también podrías ver todos los resultados antes de ser filtrados.

Es decir que no es para datos secretos :). Para algo así, y quitando del medio el cifrado del canal que es otro tema, necesitas implementar algo por lo menos en php.

**EDIT 1**

Ejemplo código revisado.

Archivo data.json:
Colocarlo en el directorio raiz del webserver.

```
{
    "personas":[
        {"nombre":"Pepe","apellido":"Trueno"},
        {"nombre":"Kava","apellido":"Zorro"},
        {"nombre":"Rosa","apellido":"Melo"},
        {"nombre":"Elmo","apellido":"Jones"},
        {"nombre":"Gato","apellido":"Negro"}
    ]
}
```

Archivo html con javascript (y jQuery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SOes75347</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&quot;Mostrar los datos&quot; muestra los datos ya bajados y guardados en miApp.data. Antes de bajar los datos no hay nada cargado.</p>
<p>&quot;Buscar los datos&quot; baja el archivo json, y lo almacena en miApp.data dejándo la información disponible para ser usada.</p>
<p>Despu&eacute;s de bajar los datos, &quot;Mostrar los datos&quot; muestra los datos en un div.</p>
<br>
<button id="btnBuscar">Buscar los datos</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="btnMostrar">Mostrar los datos</button>
<br>
<div id="divMostrar"></div>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

function buscarDatos(){ //La función podría recibir un parámetro 
    //con el criterio a filtrar
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {

        //Acá podés aplicar lógica de filtrado.
        //El criterio puede ser pasado como parametro o 
        // estar previamente seteado en miApp.xxxx
        //Y así quedarte con solo los registros que queres;

        miApp.data = data; // Al especificar dataType: 'json' 
                // jQuery hace la conversión

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
        //Mostrar algun eror
        }
    });
};

function mostrarDatos(){
    if(miApp.data.personas != null){
        var texto = "";
        for(var i=0; i< miApp.data.personas.length; i++){
            texto = texto + miApp.data.personas[i].nombre + " " + miApp.data.personas[i].apellido + "<br>"; 
        }
        $("#divMostrar").html(texto);
    }
}


var MiApp = function(){
    this.data = [];
}

var miApp = new MiApp();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnBuscar").click(function(e){
          var event = e || window.event;
          if(event.preventDefault){
              event.preventDefault();
          }else{
              event.returnValue = false;
          }
             buscarDatos();
          if(event.stopPropagation){
              event.stopPropagation();
          }else{
              event.cancelBubble = true;
          }
    });

    $("#btnMostrar").click(function(e){
          var event = e || window.event;
          if(event.preventDefault){
              event.preventDefault();
          }else{
              event.returnValue = false;
          }
             mostrarDatos();
          if(event.stopPropagation){
              event.stopPropagation();
          }else{
              event.cancelBubble = true;
          }
    });


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Crees poder darme una ayuda mas personalizada.

Comment: Intente hacerlo pero no lo logre. https://farmacialimon.neocities.org/probando/index.html

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo de como hacer la bajada y una forma de mostrar los datos bajados.

Answer (score 0):

@josue Gonzales si deseas hacer una tabla con datos ficticios te recomendaría que uses este plugin es bastante bueno ya que busca los datos según lo que quieres.

https://datatables.net/

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya</td>
                <td>Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena</td>
                <td>Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde</td>
                <td>Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley</td>
                <td>Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana</td>
                <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria</td>
                <td>Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai</td>
                <td>Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette</td>
                <td>Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri</td>
                <td>Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar</td>
                <td>Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris</td>
                <td>Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica</td>
                <td>Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden</td>
                <td>Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona</td>
                <td>Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou</td>
                <td>Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle</td>
                <td>House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki</td>
                <td>Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott</td>
                <td>Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena</td>
                <td>Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard</td>
                <td>Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope</td>
                <td>Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian</td>
                <td>Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy</td>
                <td>Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno</td>
                <td>Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura</td>
                <td>Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor</td>
                <td>Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn</td>
                <td>Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge</td>
                <td>Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo, es muy completo ya los e visto antes pero no logro modificarlos a mi necesidad. Que basicamente es que lo datos no esten visibles y que el filtro se haga hasta que no le de click al boton buscar.

Comment: @JosueGonzalez facil entones crea un comando con css que todo lo que es la parte de datos de tu tabla lo pongas invisible y cuando busque que se ponga para que lo vean . me explico ? pero la cuestion que ya con ese plugin lo haras

Answer (score 0):

A partir de HTML5 puedes guardar datos en una base de datos local **usando solamente HTML/Javascript**. Existe también almacenamiento por sesión.

Puedes echarle un vistazo a la documentación:

- [API de almacenamiento web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/API_de_almacenamiento_web)
- [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo mínimo que muestra la forma de almacenar, leer y borrar datos usando `localStorage`.

Se pueden hacer más cosas avanzadas, como configurar la BD para que funcione off-line, almacenar datos en tablas / columnas específicas, etc... es cuestión de explorar.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/hrvhrkbk/4/)**</kbd>

**HTML**:

```
<input id="myData" type="text" placeholder="Escriba los datos..." />
<br />
<button onclick="createData()">Crear</button>
<button onclick="readData()">Leer</button>
<button onclick="deleteData()">Borrar</button>
<hr />
<div id="info"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
//array para guardar los valores
var arrData = Array();

//Identificar el elemento input
var inputData = document.getElementById('myData');

//Crear datos en local storage
function createData() {
    //Obtiene el valor actual del input
        var strDataToSave = inputData.value;
    if ((strDataToSave == null) || (strDataToSave == "")) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "El input está vacío.";
    } else {
        //Envía valor del input al array
        arrData.push(strDataToSave);
        //Limpia el input 
        inputData.value = "";
        //Guarda el valor en el local storage llamado database agregando un espacio en blanco
        window.localStorage.setItem("database", arrData.join(" "));
        //Confirma en pantalla que los datos se guardaron
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "¡Datos guardados!";
        //Limpia el mensaje de info después de 1 segundo
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
        }, 1000);

    }
}

// Leer datos
function readData() {
    //Obtiene el valor del local storage "database" por llave (key)
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("database") == null) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "¡No hay datos!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 
                         window.localStorage.getItem("database");
    }
}

//Borrar datos almacenados
function deleteData() {
    //Limpia el storage
    arrData = Array();
    localStorage.clear("database");
    //Imprimir mensaje
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "¡Datos borrados!";
}
```

**CSS**:

```
#info {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: red;
}
```