# ¿Cómo limpiar localstorage con jquery o javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente variable de sesión del lado del cliente:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("pendienteedi",pendiente);
```

Pero deseo limpiarla, ¿Cómo se realiza?

Comment: [Mira si este ejemplo te sirve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75372/29967). Muestra como leer, borrar o actualizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres eliminar solo esa variable debes utilizar

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("pendienteedi");
```

Si quieres limpiar toda la sessionStorage existe la función

```
sessionStorage.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 localStorage.clear();
```

Esto limpia el local Storage